# New attribute in local, undefined in staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

I've added a new attribute column to my Tags table, and in local it's working fine.
But in heroku, even though I've done the `heroku run rake db:migrate`and the new columns have been created, Its giving me an error when creating a new tag.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `price_type' for #<Tag:0x007fc3180e9448>):
```

Why is this happening in staging and not in development?

EDIT:

Migration file

```
class AddPriceTypetoTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :tags, :price_type, :integer
    add_column :tags, :max_price, :integer
    rename_column :tags, :price, :min_price
  end
end
```

My heroku logs

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --remote staging
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.7489
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
Migrating to AddPriceTypetoTags (20140611231324)
==  AddPriceTypetoTags: migrating =============================================
-- add_column(:tags, :price_type, :integer)
   -> 0.0103s
-- add_column(:tags, :max_price, :integer)
   -> 0.0013s
-- rename_column(:tags, :price, :min_price)
   -> 0.0064s
==  AddPriceTypetoTags: migrated (0.0188s) ====================================
```

Comment: Should be `heroku run rake db:migrate`. Looks like that's probably just a typo when you created the question though.

Comment: @Justin thats what I did sorry, I had a typo in my question.

Comment: It doesn't work... tables are migrated but the error persists.

Comment: Would you mind posting your migration file please? The one when you added this column. Thanks

Comment: There u have! @Justin

Comment: Maybe restarting Heroku server?

Comment: Whenever you deploy to Heroku, the Heroku server should automatically restart. But that command should be `heroku restart`

Comment: Ok that was it. Restarting the server did it... I thought it would do it automatically. So silly. Thanks for your time Justin